# Comment removal policy

Tags: discussion, comments

I have seen two of my comments, asking for further details on the question asked, removed.

The questions were these:

[How do Proteins migrate in MES vs. MOPS](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1681/691)

[How do SDS-PAGE gels differ in a Bis-Tris system vs. a Tris-Glycine system?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1680/691)

Apparently, my comments were *to the point* since the author edited his questions accordingly. I was not advised that my comments had been removed, nor was I told *why*. I found out only by going back to the question, out of interest, to see if the inquirer had responded.

Who decides when and which comments are removed?

Comment: Looking at the comments that were removed I'd say it was because they had served their purpose - the user had taken on board your feedback rendering them obsolete?

Comment: That's why I'm asking, what's the policy? Go ahead and write an answer if you have something to say about it!

Answer (score 7):

Comments are removed when they are obsolete or excessive noise.

Comments are meant to be ephemeral supplements to questions and answers on SE, mostly to ask for clarification. When a comment is no longer necessary it may be removed to reduce noise for future visitors.

The power of the Stack Exchange system is that noise is reduced to a minimum, future visitors to your questions/answers should be able to get in and out and get the information they want, too many comments can hinder that, so it's up to moderator's discretion when to remove comments. Consider removing your own comments after they have been addressed.

Comment: Sure, I agree. Then how are cases like [this one](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1663/691) one handled?

Comment: @CHM now that these too are no longer relevant, they will be purged after a while :)

Comment: @CHM actually posts gaining more than 20 comments in a short period of time are automatically flagged, so they should be dealt with in due time.

Answer (score 6):

I removed the comments because they were obsolete. The changes you asked for were made and those comments not necessary anymore.

Unrelated to my removal of those comments, I also think that it's not really necessary to elaborate on those very common buffer systems. Someone able to answer those questions is likely familiar with them, or has at least heard that those buffers exist.

Comment: Fair enough for the removal, but I'm concerned that your way of thinking is a bit discriminatory. I'm a chemist, and can answer the question as well as any biochemist. I just need the background information. Surely everybody reading this isn't acquainted with those buffers?

Comment: It takes about 10 seconds to google them, they are just trivial names of common chemicals. I don't think we need to link all chemicals that are mentioned in a post.

Comment: You're telling me that if I need more information on a question, I have the responsibility to look it up - that the author doesn't need to provide me such precisions. Doesn't that inhibit collaboration?

Comment: No, I'm saying that all the necessary information was present in the question. The author used the correct trivial names for the chemicals, those are sufficient for identifying them. I don't think we need IUPAC names for all chemicals or something like that.

Comment: As the OP, I placed the links and edits as pure courtesy to CHM. However, as Mad Scientist implies, any "expert" should immediately know what I was talking about. Since they are my target audience, this type of jargon is permissible.

Comment: I think reasonable other jargon would include TAE, TBE, DTT, SDS-PAGE, T7, Da, kb, HEPES, and Kd. All abbreviations that I assume my colleague @MadScientist should recognize despite the fact that we are constantly asking each other for clarifications.