# Comment deletion?

Tags: discussion, comments

In reference to the [question about whether the mRNA or the ribosome move during translation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/rna-or-ribosome-which-one-moves-during-translation#comment2269_1742), a number of the comments do not add anything to the understanding of answers or constructively promote conversation. In fact, some of them seem to be a leaning towards personal attacks.

Without flagging a lot of the comments individually, I would suggest a mod remove the unnecessary comments as per the guidelines set out in the [comment removal policy question](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219/comment-removal-policy) here on meta.Bio.

What are your thoughts on the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've removed a couple of comments from [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/1740/69) that were not adding much in addition to a couple from the question itself.  As it's late, I'm sleepy and not wanting to be heavy handed because of it would you mind raising *a couple* of flags on anything else that you think needs to be pruned in that question?

Comment: It looks much cleaner and civil already. ty.